# Orange and Black bugs on balloon plant

Tags: identification, insects

I saw these taking over a balloon plant in the area of South Bay, LA (Redondo Beach, CA).
Are they beneficial insects?[image: orange bugs clustering around balloon plant]
[image]

Comment: I don't think these are beneficials but they need ID for sure before any treatment.  Take a look at these guys, Stink Bugs. What do you think?  https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A86.JyhfQ7ZZNAwAz0onnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTEyYmg0NGU4BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDQjQxMjJfMQRzZWMDc2M-?p=stink+bugs+pictures&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002#id=364&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fswanson-media.com%2Fphotos%2Flightboxes%2Fnature%2Finsects%2Ftrue_bugs%2Fstink%2Fsource%2Fimage%2F2014_0678.jpg&action=click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're  milkweed bugs, mostly immature ones in various stages. They're usually found on Asclepias - I'm not sure what you mean by Balloon plant, that common name is usually taken to mean Platycodon, but quite why they're on that plant I don't know. Milkweed bugs have piercing mouthparts and feed on milkweed, more information, and images of the bugs in various stages of development, here:

[Milkweed bugs](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/pests-and-problems/insects/plant-bugs/milkweed-bugs.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Bamboo! I didn't know it was an asclepia. ID'd as Gomphocarpus Physocarpus / Balloon Plant after doing some search. There are tons of these bugs around here.

Comment: Ah, right - Gomphocarpus being a type of milkweed, Well that explains the bugs' presence then!